# Android hello world Ram

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ram

I'm new to android development and I'm building my first app,

Something is extremely strange, the default hello World app that comes by default, is showing a usage of 50 Mb of memory on my phone (I saw this on the Monitor that monitors CPU, GPU and Memory live on android studio). And I can't help but wonder how weird that is for a small app to take this much RAM.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Thank you in advance
[Image of the Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hq4Sr.png)

Comment: any screenshots/dumps supporting your claim?

Comment: depends on what type of device you are using , the same app can use  various RAM according to the availability so more the RAM you have more will be the use

Comment: @SakchhamSharma I added an image of it